# CURL via linha de comando funciona, mas com biblioteca curl do php retorna timeout

Tags: php, libcurl, docker, guzzle, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação em Laravel que roda com Docker dentro de uma VM na Azure em produção. 
Como ambiente de desenvolvimento, utilizo a mesma estrutura de Docker localmente, em um Ubuntu.

Existe uma funcionalidade que realiza um POST através de CURL para outro servidor, passando um SQL como parâmetro para esse servidor realizar a consulta no banco de dados e devolver a resposta. Atualmente a resposta é apenas o caminho do arquivo gerado com os resultados da consulta.

**Problema:** Ao executar esse CURL em produção (Laravel + Docker + Azure), caso a consulta no banco de dados demore mais do que 4min em média, acaba ocorrendo o timeout que é definido no momento do CURL, mesmo que a requisição REAL (testado via Insmonia, ou ambiente de desenvolvimento) leve menos tempo do que o timeout definido.

**Observações importantes:**
1. O problema ocorre apenas em produção (Laravel + Docker + Azure), executando no ambiente local de desenvolvimento funciona.
2. Utilizando qualquer ferramenta de rest client (Insomnia, Postman), funciona normalmente.
3. Executando um curl nativo (linha de comando) funciona no ambiente de produção. Ex:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://ip:port/route \
  --data '{"sql": "select 1 from dual"}'
```

4. Executando esse curl nativo da linha de comando dentro de uma função "exec()" do php no ambiente de produção também funciona.
5. Está sendo utilizado a bibilioteca de CURL GuzzleHttp, versão 6.x
6. Testado com o curl nativo do php `curl()` também não funciona em produção

**Comparativo de execuções do mesmo comando**
**Produção:** Timeout definido: 600 segundos, execução interrompida pelo timeout

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| [04/03/2020 11:44:15] Executando consulta |
+-------------------------------------------+
*   Trying IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to IP (IP) port PORT (#0)
> POST /consultas/csv HTTP/1.1
Host: IP:PORT
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.0.33
Authorization: CUSTOM TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 956

* upload completely sent off: 956 out of 956 bytes
* Operation timed out after 600001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

**Dev:** Timeout definido: 600 segundos, execução concluída após 5min48s.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| [04/03/2020 11:59:33] Executando consulta |
+-------------------------------------------+
*   Trying IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to IP (IP) port PORT (#0)
> POST /consultas/csv HTTP/1.1
Host: IP:PORT
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.0.33
Authorization: CUSTOM TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 956

* upload completely sent off: 956 out of 956 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 14:59:01 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Powered-By: :-)
< Content-Length: 52
< Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host IP left intact
+-------------------------------------------+
| [04/03/2020 12:05:14] Processando retorno |
+-------------------------------------------+
| consultas/importacao/importacao1.csv      |
+-------------------------------------------+
+-------------------------------------------+
| [04/03/2020 12:05:16] Inserindo registros |
+-------------------------------------------+
 41946/41946 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Inicio              | Fim                 | Tarefa               | Tenant    | Registros | Duração  |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 04/03/2020 11:59:33 | 04/03/2020 12:05:21 | importa_movimentacao | tenant    | 41946     | 00:05:48 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Tenta pegar o log de erro e coloca ele aqui, assim a gente consegue te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Adicionei ao final da pergunta os logs.

Comment: Se está tendo problemas apenas com timeout e você sabe quanto tempo aproximadamente a requisição leva, experimenta definir tal valor como [parâmetro de configuração da Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#connect-timeout)

Comment: O problema não é o timeout, a questão é que em produção, se o timeout não estiver definido, a requisição continua por tempo indeterminado, mesmo que o endpoint já tenha terminado a execução. Nesse caso de produção, o timeout estava definido em 10minutos, por isso parou após esse tempo, já testei até com 60minutos, e foi o tempo que demorou até ocorrer o timeout.